# Strip double qoutes only from the numbers JS

Tags: php, regex

I have the following object:

```
[["Jan","0"],["Feb","0"],["Mar","0"],["Apr","0"],["May","0"],["Jun","0"],["Jul","0"],["Aug","86"],["Sep","211"],["Oct","223"],["Nov","147"],["Dec","149"]]
```

I need it to look like:

```
[["Jan",0],["Feb",0],["Mar",0],["Apr",0],["May",0],["Jun",0],["Jul",0],["Aug",86],["Sep","211],["Oct",223],["Nov",147],["Dec",149]]
```

I generate it via PHP json_encode($var); how could i remove the qoutes only around the numbers via Regex in Javascript?

PHP

```
function specialtest()
{
    $data = [];
    $year = 2015;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $sql = 'SELECT count(*) as count FROM reservations WHERE YEAR(start) = ' . $year . ' AND MONTH(start)=' . $i;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $results = $query->result_array();
        $data[] = [date('M', strtotime($year . '-' . $i . '-01')), $results[0]['count']];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove quotes from number?

Comment: Why? It's easier to modify your PHP to coerce such "numbers" to numbers.

Comment: Can you show your PHP array/object which is being converted to JSON?

Comment: @anubhava I have added the PHP

Comment: **1.** Parse the string to JSON using `JSON.parse(response)` **2.** Use `map` on array as `arr = arr.map(function(e) {
    return [e[0], +e[1]];
});`

Comment: Looks like you can tell `json_encode` to not put quotes around the numbers with the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option.  That would save you from having to remove the quotes after the fact.  http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your line:

```
$data[] = [date('M', strtotime($year . '-' . $i . '-01')), $results[0]['count']];
```

to:

```
$data[] = [date('M', strtotime($year . '-' . $i . '-01')), (int) $results[0]['count']];
```

And this should do the trick.

More in topic would be to run on your jsonized string something like

```
preg_replace('/\"(\d)\"/', '\1', json_encode(array('a' => '1')))
```